# Android получение кординат gps

Tags: java, android, gps

В логах нули.

```
public class GpsLocation {
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    public static final String TAG = "gps_debug_logs";

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();

            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude=" + location.getLatitude());
            Log.d(TAG, "longitude=" + location.getLongitude());    
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }


    };

    public double getLatitude() {    
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
}
```

Пермишн есть 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE"/>`

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте такой пермишн `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: Все равно нули.